# JPA 2.5 CriteriaQuery conditional child entities

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria

I'm have an entity

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "CONTACT")
public class ContactEntity {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contact")
    private List<PhoneEntity> phones;

    ...
}

@Table(name = "CONTACT_PHONE")
@Entity
public class PhoneEntity {
    @Column(name = "DEVICE_TYPE")
    private String deviceType;

    ...
}
```

When I select my entity using `CriteriaBuilder`, I want to filter phones owned by Contact by some perticular field. For example, by deviceType. Is it possible using Criteria API?

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ContactEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ContactEntity.class);
Root<ContactEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(ContactEntity.class);
List<ContactEntity> contactSnapshotEntities =
            entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Comment: *When I select my entity*: which entity, using which code?

Comment: I have added code example of selection.

Comment: JPA 2.5 ? WTF? JPA is 1.0, 2.0 or 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask a Contact entity for its phones, you'll always get all the phones of this Contact entity, whatever the way you obtained the Contact entity. That's the contract of your class: a Contact has many phones, available using the getPhones() method.

If you want a subset of the phones of a Contact entity, then you should not get the Contact and get its phones. You should use a query which returns another collection, which only contains the phones matching the criteria. For example:

```
select p from Phone p where p.contact = :contact and p.deviceType = :deviceType
```

(or the same query obfuscated by the criteria API).